# Why does scheduleWithFixedDelay only run once?

Tags: android, image, camera

My program is suppose to store a `byte[]` image from the camera in an `ArrayList` every 250 ms.

I am testing the same code on 2 separate devices:
 the first is a Nexus 7 running Android 4.4.2 and the second is a Nexus 10 running Android 4.4.3.

The Nexus 7 runs the `scheduleWithFixedDelay` function perfectly, but the Nexus 10 does not. The Nexus 10 runs it once and then stops.

```
class RunnableCamera implements Runnable {

    ScheduledExecutorService serviceCam = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        startCamera CAM = new startCamera();

        serviceCam.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable()
        {

            @Override
            public void run()
            {   
                camera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);

            }
          }, 0, 250, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            camera.startPreview(); 

            imagesArrayList.add(data);
            Log.d("image", "byte[] added to ArrayList");

        }
    };

    public class startCamera implements Callback {

        //private Camera camera;
        private SurfaceHolder holder = null;

        public startCamera() {
            videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vwCamera);

            holder = videoView.getHolder();
            holder.addCallback(this);

            Log.d("bro", "startCamera() constructor");
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            try {
                Log.i("bro", "surfaceCreated");
                camera = Camera.open(0);

                camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

                if (camera != null) {
                    camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

                } else {
                    Log.i("bro", "camera = null");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Could not start the preview-Display123");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            Log.i("bro", "surfaceChanged");

            //Sets correct preview resolution 
            if (holder.getSurface() == null){
                Log.i("bro", "holder.getSurface() == null");
                return;
            }

            Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
            Log.i("bro", "camera.getParameters();");

            sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            Log.i("bro", "parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();");
            Camera.Size optimalSize = getBestPreviewSize(width, height);
            try {
                parameters.setPreviewSize(optimalSize.width, optimalSize.height);
                camera.setParameters(parameters);

            } catch (NullPointerException a) {

            }

            Log.i("bro", "startPreview()");
            camera.startPreview();

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            Log.i("bro", "surfaceDestroyed");
            if (camera != null) {
                camera.stopPreview();
                camera.release();
                Log.i("bro", "CAMERA STOPPED");
            }

        }

        private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height) {
            Camera.Size result = null;
            Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
            for (Camera.Size size : p.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
                if (size.width <= width && size.height <= height) {
                    if (result == null) {
                        result = size;
                    } else {
                        int resultArea = result.width * result.height;
                        int newArea = size.width * size.height;

                        if (newArea > resultArea) {
                            result = size;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;

        } 

    }

}
```

In my onCreate method I start the Runnable class like:

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(new RunnableCamera());
thread1.start();
```

If I change the time delay to 600 ms, the Nexus 10 runs it perfectly. I'm wondering if this is a device issue with the first generation Nexus 10, an Android 4.4.3 issue or something wrong with my code. Is there a better way to do this?